# Angular ag-grid projects works locally but not on server: compiling errors

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

i use ag-grid in my project, running it locally with ng serve works fine and as expected. But when uploading to the server the compiling allways fails with basically the following error:

```
ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(87,5): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'

  Could not resolve ag-grid-angular relative to c:/workspace/.../Angular/src/app/app.module.ts..

src/app.../status-cellrenderer.component.ts(2,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ag-grid-angular'.

src/app/app.module.ts(36,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ag-grid-angular'.
```

i use ag-grid version 20.0.0 and used this tutorial: https://medium.com/ag-grid/get-started-with-angular-grid-in-5-minutes-83bbb14fac93

edit:
this is the configuration on the server:

```
cd Angular
cmd /c call npm install 
@ECHO ############ Node.js Packages installed  ###################
REM cmd /c call node_modules/.bin/ng --version
@ECHO ############ Build Angular-Site  ##################
cmd /c call node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --output-path=..\PublishOutput
```

the nodes_modules directory is not uploaded by myself..

Comment: Have you set up your build server to retrieve missing npm-packages (npm install)? Usually the node_modules folder is and sould not be commited with your source code.

Comment: i have edited the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the node_modules directory solved the problem